# how to divide huge xml file into smaller ones

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath, sax

I have a gigantic xml file, and I need to do some processing and that of course will be time consuming. I thought about dividing the main xml file into smaller xml files. my question is, is there any recommended approach or library that can do this job or i have to develop the algorithm.

Comment: why you are not using stax of sax parser ? You could really parse gigantic xml file using these and store in DB for further processing.

Comment: check out Stax as Navveen said. Also, this previous post might offer some useful info. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3969713/java-xml-parser-for-huge-files

Comment: @NaveenRamawat do u mean, instead of dividing the huge xml file, i just need to to process itwith sax?or u mean, that i should use sax for dividing the big file?

Comment: I meant sax or better would be stax to process the xml. Finally you are going to process the XML, Or you can use XPath in SAX parser , Using XPath you can read particular chunk of XML see it https://code.google.com/p/xpath4sax/

Comment: @NaveenRamawat kindly please bear with me, now i checked some tutorials about stax, and i know how to use xpath. so to divide the large xml file should i combine using both? stax for locating the startTags and so on and xpath for retrieving the data? or i need to use stax and convert it to DOM..please advise

Comment: I think Naveen does not mean that you would divide the big XML file into smaller files; instead you would use sax/stax to process the XML without having to store it all in memory at once.

Comment: DOM parser will create entire XML in memory but as you have huge XML than DOM will not be a solution, Just parse your XML with Stax it is simple and fast and store data in somewhere in DB and use DB data further. You will no required the XML break.